# Disparar evento al dar click a una celda de un GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Estoy tratando de abrir una pagina nueva al darle click a cualquier celda de un `GridView` alguien sabe si esto es posible ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:GridView ID="GV_Gastos" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GV_Gastos_RowDataBound" CssClass="grid-view" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" Font-Names="century gothic,small" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="1000px" DataSourceID="DS_Gastos" ShowFooter="True">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderRojo" />
                <RowStyle CssClass="normal" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternate" />
                <PagerStyle ForeColor="#CC0000" Font-Bold="true" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="GASTO" FooterText="Total" HeaderText="Tipo de Gasto" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="GASTO" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                        <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemStyle BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True"/>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ANTERIOR" HeaderText="ANTERIOR" SortExpression="ANTERIOR"  DataFormatString="{0:c}" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UNO" HeaderText="UNO" SortExpression="UNO"  DataFormatString="{0:c}" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="15%" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DOS" HeaderText="DOS"  SortExpression="DOS"  DataFormatString="{0:c}" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                        <ItemStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="10%" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TRES" HeaderText="TRES" SortExpression="TRES"  DataFormatString="{0:c}" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                        <ItemStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CUATRO" HeaderText="CUATRO" SortExpression="CUATRO"  DataFormatString="{0:c}" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                        <ItemStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CINCO" HeaderText="CINCO" SortExpression="CINCO"  DataFormatString="{0:c}" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                        <ItemStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SEIS" HeaderText="SEIS" SortExpression="SEIS"  DataFormatString="{0:c}" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                        <ItemStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TOTAL" HeaderText="TOTAL" SortExpression="TOTAL"  DataFormatString="{0:c}" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                        <ItemStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RESPONSABLE" HeaderText="RESPONSABLE" SortExpression="RESPONSABLE" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                        <ItemStyle Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
                        <RowStyle BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" Font-Bold="False" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS_Gastos" runat="server" ConnectionString="ejemplo" SelectCommand="ejemplo" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="102" Name="ACCION" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ejemplo" DefaultValue="ejemplo" Name="ejemplo" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ejemplo" DefaultValue="ejemplo" Name="ejemplo" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ejemplo" DefaultValue="" Name="IDRESPONSABLE" PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: puedes agregar tu codigo? como lo estas haciendo? que has probado?

Comment: Ademas de ver codigo (de como lo estas haciendo) seria útil que nos menciones o comentes cual es la funcionalidad que estas necesitando, por ejemplo que "... al hacer click en cualquier fila haga esto...." (asi podremos ver si es necesario postback o solo codigo del lado del cliente con javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tienes dos opciones, o hacemos postback porque necesitas realizar acciones del lado del servidor o directamente hacemos el enlace en el click del gridview... para eso te dejo las dos opciones

- **OPCION 1: Como seleccionar la fila/row del gridview directamente con
  un click en la fila/row**
- **OPCION 2: Como hacer un enlace en la fila de un gridview (al hacer click)**

Vamos por partes... pero en tu caso como dice un hipervinculo entonces es la OPCION 2 la que necesitas.

**OPCION 1: Como seleccionar la fila/row del gridview directamente con
   un click en la fila/row**
Puedes en el evento utilizar el metodo [GetPostBackClientHyperlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms153108(v=vs.110).aspx) para justtamente lo que dice el nombre del metodo, obtener el enlace para hacer postback... que lo debes registrar en cada fila en el evento onclick de javascript haciendo cuando se enlaza a datos cada fila o sea en el evento [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)

La idea

```
protected void GV_Gastos_OnRowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){
    e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GV_Gastos, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    e.Row.ToolTip = "Haga click para seleccionar la fila.";

}
}
```

Aqui tienes que por cada click (tambien lo puedes hacer con dobleclick en el evento del lado delc liente ondblclick) se disparara el evento de seleccion del
gridview (con un comando especial "Select" y el argumento que necesita
es el numero de la fila)
En el evento [SelectedIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que deberias realizar las acciones que deseas con la fila seleccionada

```
void GV_Gastos_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
   GridViewRow row = GV_Gastos.SelectedRow;
   //acciones...
}
```

NOTA: Si te da error deberias setear la variable en la pagina (o en el webconfig si quieres para toda la app)

> <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GridviewBasic.aspx.cs" 
>       **EnableEventValidation="false"** ...

**OPCION 2: Como hacer un enlace en la fila de un gridview (al hacer click)**
Aqui la opcion 2 es identica a la 1 solo que no hay postback, que justo es lo que necesitas.. es agregar al onclick la apertura del enlace que quieres (si quieres en la misma pagina tambien se pueda depende del javascript que coloques)
Algo asi

```
   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:window.open('https://es.stackoverflow.com', 'Demo', 'width=800,height=800')";
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Haga click para seleccionar la fila.";
        }
    }
```

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)

Se produce cuando una fila de datos se enlaza a datos en un GridView control.